# Pandas timedelta computes only time (ignoring the date)?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta, data-processing

I have a bunch of dates of the format :

```
0    2021-12-07 12:42:56
1    2021-12-14 12:20:28
2    2022-02-03 13:41:33
3    2022-02-17 10:07:37
4    2022-02-22 13:02:02


0    2021-14-07 13:00:13
1    2021-12-14 12:39:01
2    2022-05-03 13:00:53
3    2022-02-17 10:45:23
4    2022-02-22 13:17:41
```

for the beginning and the end of the event. I need to calculate duration:

```
    t1 = pd.to_datetime(for_test['Start'])
    t2 = pd.to_datetime(for_test['End'])
    list_of_time_difference = []
    list_of_ind = []
    for i in range (0, len (t2)): 
        list_of_time_difference.append(pd.Timedelta(t2[i] - t1[i]).seconds / 3600.0)
        if list_of_time_difference[-1] > 24: 
            list_of_ind.append(i)
```

But it looks that when I calculate the time difference ignoring the date, and take into consideration time only. I had hope that timedelta would give the difference between two dates and time

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The dates are weird, You have both 2021-14-07 and 2022-02-17 in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), the attribute `seconds` gives you

> Number of seconds (>= 0 and less than 1 day).

Check out the doc for attributes/methods of your interest.